# Deployment failure of Freemarker based spring boot application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, freemarker

I’ve a Spring boot application with (.ftl) freemarker-based multiple file upload form, that works fine locally. However, deploying on AWS ElasticBeanstalk kept failing, doesn't display the upload form at all. I've tried different packaging options jar/war, and platforms java/tomcat yet the problem is still there. I would appreciate any idea on how to deploy .ftl based application on ElasticBeanstalk. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it has something to do with not being able to find the ftl files. Can you see the error log? Do you have some code on how you are loading the template?

Comment: Error log: s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Comment: That error message won't help. Are there any other specific errors?

Comment: o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer         : ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http)
c.j.uploadingfiles.MyApplication         : Started MyApplication in 18.405 seconds (JVM running for 23.721)
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: At first glance, looks like your error is not related to free-marker. Can you eliminate references to free-marker and deploy the code?

Comment: though the problem doesn't seem to be related with the free-marker template, it never shows up on startup, sorry can I share you my code? thnaks in advance!

Comment: fixed! set in application.properties, spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=file:./templates/, classpath:/templates/, after copying the .ftl file into /resources/templates/

Comment: you will only need need either the "file:..." or the "classpath:...". so you might  want to remove one and leave one that works to avoid confusion or configuration drift in the future.

Comment: thanks a lot! The idea is to upload multiple plain text files and process them in two alternative ways: parallel (multiple servers based) and single-multicore based server. I've already deployed on the web-server option of elasticbeanstalk, but not sure how to experiment the two ways. While I'm exploring, do you please have any quick pointers?